# Website opens and closes immediatly during scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

Every time i run this code, the website opens and then closes immediately, i've tried different types of correction but nothing really works. I tried to install the chrome driver but also didn't work and showed a different error. Also my variable "matches" doens't receive any value and keeps printing a empty list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed")

all_matches_button = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, '//label[@analytics-event="All matches"]'
)
all_matches_button.click()

season = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="season"]')
season.click()

s_2022 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="season"]/option[2]')
s_2022.click()

matches = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

date = []
home_team = []
score = []
away_team = []

print(matches)

for match in matches:
    date.append(match.find_element(By.XPATH, "./td[1]").text)
    home = match.find_element(By.XPATH, "./td[2]").text
    print(home)
    score.append(match.find_element(By.XPATH, "./td[3]").text)
    away_team.append(match.find_element(By.XPATH, "./td[4]").text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the whole [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) and get the data directly in Json form  using the Ajax request. For example:

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/scripts/data/json/scripts/pages/overs/detailed/overs_league_json.php"

# this params corresponds to "England"/"Championship"/"Season 23/24"
params = {"clflc": "abc", "league": "E1", "season": "23/24"}

headers = {
    "Authorization-Client": "ADAMCHOI.CO.UK",
}

data = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "teams": [
        {
            "teamName": "Birmingham",
            "allMatches": [
                {
                    "date": "05-08-2023",
                    "homeTeam": "Swansea",
                    "result": "1 - 1",
                    "awayTeam": "Birmingham",
                    "isOver15": True,
                    "isOver25": False,
                    "isOver35": False,
                },
                {
                    "date": "12-08-2023",
                    "homeTeam": "Birmingham",
                    "result": "? - ?",
                    "awayTeam": "Leeds",
                    "isOver15": False,
                    "isOver25": False,
                    "isOver35": False,
                },
            ],
            "homeOver15": [0, 0, "nan", 0],
            "homeOver25": [0, 0, "nan", 0],
            "homeOver35": [0, 0, "nan", 0],
            "awayOver15": [1, 1, "100.0", 1],
            "awayOver25": [1, 0, "0.0", 0],
            "awayOver35": [1, 0, "0.0", 0],
            "overallOver15": [1, 1, "100.0", 1],
            "overallOver25": [1, 0, "0.0", 0],
            "overallOver35": [1, 0, "0.0", 0],
        },

...and so on.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can skip the whole selenium and get the data directly in Json form using the Ajax request